# ReactJS POSTrequest does'nt work(404) but GETrequest works

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs, axios

I have a very strange problem, when I POST to my PHP file it returns a 404 status code and when I do a GET request it gets me a status code of 200.
I have tried my requests with XMLHttpRequest, Fetch, Axios and jquery but all give the same response.
What am I doing wrong?

These are my ajax requests.

```
const body = { firstName: 'Fred',lastName: 'Flintstone' };
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
e.preventDefault()
fetch(`ajaxHandler.php`)
.then(res => 
console.log(res)
)
fetch('ajaxHandler.php', {
method: 'POST',
// mode: 'CORS',
body: JSON.stringify(body),
headers: {
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
}).then(res => {
console.log(res);
}).catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

POST request response from the console.

```
login.js:20 POST http://localhost:3000/ajaxHandler.php 404 (Not Found)
handleSubmit @ login.js:20
onClick @ login.js:65
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:336
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:385
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:440
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:454
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:584
executeDispatchesInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:609
executeDispatchesAndRelease @ react-dom.development.js:713
executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel @ react-dom.development.js:722
forEachAccumulated @ react-dom.development.js:694
runEventsInBatch @ react-dom.development.js:739
runExtractedPluginEventsInBatch @ react-dom.development.js:880
handleTopLevel @ react-dom.development.js:5803
batchedEventUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:24401
batchedEventUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:1415
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem @ react-dom.development.js:5894
attemptToDispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6010
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:5914
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:697
runWithPriority$2 @ react-dom.development.js:12149
discreteUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:24417
discreteUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:1438
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js:5881
login.js:28 Response {type: "basic", url: "http://localhost:3000/ajaxHandler.php", redirected: false, status: 404, ok: false, …}
```

GET response from console

```
login.js:16 Response {type: "basic", url: "http://localhost:3000/ajaxHandler.php", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
```

ajaxHandler (PHP) code

```
<?php
session_start();

header('Access-control-Allow-Methods: POST,GET,DELETE,OPTIONS');
header('Accept: application/json');

$response = array("success" => true, "message" => "yeahhh");

echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: The problem is clearly not with frontend (JS) but with backend (PHP). Can you please share the PHP code you use as backend (`ajaxHandler.php`)?

Comment: @MatteoMeil I have added the PHP code.

Comment: Are you calling the php script from a different origin? I.e.: the js script is run from `localhost:8000` while php serves from `localhost:3000`?

Comment: @MatteoMeil No, I'm calling my JS script from localhost:3000 and my PHP file  localhost:3000/ajaxHandler.php

Answer (score 0):

With 404 errors, a lot could be going on, networking and otherwise, but I see there are a few things that could be recommended here.

One question I need to ask is: Is the ReactJS server and the PHP server on the same web domain?  I.E., do users see your ReactJS code at example.com, but your PHP server is at example2.com?

If the servers are the same, then, in your ReactJS, try defining the `credentials` variable...

```
const fetchargs = {
    'method': method,
    'credentials': 'same-origin',
};

fetch('ajaxHandler.php', fetchargs...);
```

And if the servers are different, then change 'credentials' to `include`.  Check out the fetch() API at the [Fetch() MDN Documents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

On your PHP side, I see you are omitting the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.  Again, if you are using the same domain for both frontend/backend (ReactJS/PHP), then you'll want to set this to the domain name (as in the docs).  If the domains differ, you'll want to set it to `*`, as noted in the [CORS MDN Documents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

```
<?php

     header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://mozilla.org');

?>
```

Hope this helps!  404's can be mysterious, but I suspect that is just how your server is configured to respond when a disallowed POST is sent.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried everything you said but I still get 404... :(